# Running an R script using "Run Source" vs. "Run Without Debugging"

Tags: r, visual-studio

In VS Code on Windows, what is the difference between running an R script using the "Run Source" button (arrow icon in top-right screen corner):

[image]

versus running it using the "Run Without Debugging" command from the Run menu:

[image]

There [seems to be](https://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20studio%20code%20%22run%20source%22%20%22run%20without%20debugging%22&sxsrf=AOaemvKleWx6_Yu370Kh07nuRzrd6-PcTQ%3A1641290902944&ei=lhzUYdODOY7TkgXPpJ3gCw&ved=0ahUKEwjTpviJ7Zf1AhWOqaQKHU9SB7wQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=visual%20studio%20code%20%22run%20source%22%20%22run%20without%20debugging%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EANKBAhBGAFKBAhGGABQsQ1YsQ1gmA9oAnAAeACAAW-IAW-SAQMwLjGYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) little discussion/documentation about this, which is surprising.

Comment: Have you tried both? On my side "Run without debugging" starts the debugger but without debugging anything (eg it opens the debug tab). Meanwhile "run Source" literally executes `source("filename")` in the interactive session exactly as if I had started an R session and executed the code myself. In the prior you can choose various debugging states (depending on your installed debugger extension) while this is not the case in the prior.

Comment: I have tried both and (perhaps only in that particular case) the result seemed to be the same, so I didn't understand why we had to have two different commands. I think "Run without debugging" still doesn't allow you to execute line by line and e.g. watch variables , so I still don't understand what the differnece is

Comment: In my case it opens the debugger, on the left hand side. Basically executing nothing, at which point i can then choose to execute the debugger in various states. I'm assuming this illustrates that the effect of "without debugging" is dependent on your extensions. :-)

Comment: I see, yes, we're getting closer to the answer there! Thanks!